# Test if required package found

Tags: cmake

Let's say I need to get a package `PX`.

```
find_package(PX REQUIRED)
if(PX_FOUND)
    target_link_libraries(foo PX::lib)
endif()
```

Since I marked the package as `REQUIRED`, is the test necessary ? Is there any situation where I won't be able to link `PX` ?

Comment: No test is required; there might be such a situation if the find module/config is badly written.

Comment: A check like this should imho be written differently. `if (NOT PX_FOUND) message(FATAL_ERROR "px not found") endif() target_link_libraries(...)` Note: for package configuration files the check is unnecessary, see [the docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html): *"The package configuration file may set `<PackageName>_FOUND` to false to tell `find_package` that component requirements are not satisfied."*, i.e. in this scenario either `find_package` would detect an error because of missing config files or because the config file sets `PX_FOUND`to false resulting in error

Comment: Note find_package has a module version that's attempted to be used first and there doesn't seem to be such statement in the doc for the module version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since I marked the package as `REQUIRED`, is the test necessary?

No, it is not necessary. If no compatible module or config file on the search path sets `<PkgName>_FOUND`, then `find_package(PkgName REQUIRED)` will kill the configure step right then and there. It's a fatal error. Checking the variable is pointless. You can safely write:

```
find_package(PX REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(foo PRIVATE PX::lib)
```

Don't forget to set a visibility specifier when using `target_link_libraries`.